# How to use single variable as a multipule parameter in executesqltask in ssis

Tags: ssis

1) I created a variable in package level like `@id`

2) I want to use this variable in `Execute Sql task`
like this:

```
select 
  col1,col2 
from table
where col1=@id 
  and col2=@id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map the variables through Parameter Mapping tab on the execute SQL task.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it only once. Receive the parameter in a local variable, and use that variable in your code.

Let me explain it by an example. Hopefully, you will see what I meant by passing one parameter only once, even if it is going to be used in multiple places inside the query/code.

Also, there is an advantage is converting the received parameters to local variables. By doing so, we would not have to reconfigure the parameters if we modify the order of these parameters inside our query/code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [RecID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Result] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

--Populate the table

```
RecID     col1      col2         Result
1         10            10       R1
2         10            11       R2
3         11            11       R3
4         11            11       R4
```

-- Test this code inside SSMS first. Notice, I am declaring the variable only once.

```
DECLARE @id AS INT = 11; 

SELECT 
    col1,col2 
FROM
    Test
WHERE
     col1=@id 
     AND col2=@id;
```

-- Now all we need to do it put this code inside the Execute SQL Task Editor, and pass the parameter

In the general section:
        Result Set: Full result set
        SQLSourceType: Direct input
        SQLStatement:

```
    DECLARE @id AS INT = ?;

    SELECT 
        col1,col2 
    FROM
        Test
    WHERE
         col1=@id 
         AND col2=@id;
```

In the Parameter mapping section:

```
Variable Name: User:id (or whatever you have created in your package)
Direction: Input
Data Type: LONG (for this example)
Parameter Name: 0  
Parameter size: -1
```

In the Result set section:

```
Result Name: 0
Variable Name: User::oResultSet (or whatever you have created in your package)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Execute Sql Task Editor` in `General` tab, write your query like this:

```
select 
  col1,col2 
from table
where col1=?
  and col2=?
```

Then in `Parameter Mapping` tab add two parameters and fill:
Variable Name = [pick your variable], Direction="Input", Data Type = [pick your data type], Parameter Size = -1

Both entries should differ only by Parameter Name: 0 for first parameter, and 1 for second parameter.

Comment: @frikzoid, your solution is just fine. That's why I upvoted it. The only change I would suggest is passing one parameter only once, even if it's going to be used multiple times within query query/code. Again, the code was still correct and useful!